# How to Add HTML Between Magento PHP Generated List

Tags: php, magento

I have this list:

[image]

And I wanted to add the " | " character between the links in blue.

However, the list items are generated by PHP in the following code:

```
<ul class="links pull-right"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>
        <?php if ($_link instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract):?>
            <?php echo $_link->toHtml() ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
        <?php endif;?> |   //----------- the | character was added here ---------------
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

The problems are:

1. the PHP is in a for each loop and the | character is added to the last link as well.
2. I want to position the "Log In" somewhere else on my page. Is there a way to separate the last list item and position it elsewhere?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a way to select, for example, last element, or third element in the for each loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1:
Use `$_link->getIsLast()`. Check if it is not last -> Add your Delimiter.

```
<ul class="links pull-right"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>
        <?php if ($_link instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract):?>
            <?php echo $_link->toHtml() ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
        <?php endif;?> 
        <?php if (! $_link->getIsLast()):?>|<?php endif;?>   //----------- the | character was added here ---------------
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

That Should Work.

**EDIT:**
For Number 2:
Not 100% sure. Probably have to disable that link, then manually add it/its block's url to your layout/.phtml.

Because the link generation is automated so you would have to disable the link and then call `$something->getUrl()`
**SIMILAR** `<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('wishlist') ?>">Wishlist</a>`
**From:** [Magento add wishlist_link to different block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523489/magento-add-wishlist-link-to-different-block)